# How to raise event from class to another class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I have a solution with a VB.NET ProjectA Vb.net, and a C# ProjectB.

ProjectA has Form1.vb
ProjectB has Form1.cs and ClassBB.cs

Start project is ProjectA and Form1.vb starts with this declaration:

```
Public WithEvents PB As New ProjectA.Form1
```

And with this, i take the event:

```
Private Sub arrived() Handles PB.MatchFound
' stuff to do
end sub
```

In Form1.cs:

```
public event EventHandler MatchFound;
protected void OnMatchFound()
 {
   if (MatchFound!= null)
       MatchFound(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
```

I can fire this event from any place in Form1.cs in ProjectB.
Form1.cs also has in order to call some functions in ClassBB:

```
ClassBB ClassBB;
MyClassBB = new ClassBB();
```

I need to fire OnMatchEvent from ClassBB in order to receive the event in Form1 in ProjectA.

If i raise the event from Form1.cs from a function in ProjectB all work ok.
But i don't know how to fire the event from a function inside ClassBB.

How to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378339/raise-an-event-of-a-class-from-a-different-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can't do this, as the answer above mentions. But I don't see why you need to either. If Form1 is calling some code in classBB, then it can just fire the event when that code in classBB is finished. If you need some values from classBB in order to populate the event, then you should ensure that the method in classBB either returns those values as the return data of the event, or populates some public property in classBB from where the form code can fetch them.

Comment: Another approach would be to make classBB declare its own event. At the right moment, classBB would raise its event. Form1 would listen to that event, and when it receives it, it would raise its own event in turn. So then you have a chain of events which fire each other, and eventually the message gets to where it needs to go.

Comment: what exactly makes it necessary to fire the event from a remote class? which class finds the match? What kind of information does the event transport?

Comment: @ADyson, there is not a function to call. In classBB there is a timer working and once some condition is true, i need to fire the event ni order to Form1 in ProjectA knows the condition is true

Comment: @ADyson, how to Form1 listen to an event in ClassBB? That's what a solution.

Comment: Same way as you listen to events in your other earlier question

Comment: Doesnt work. i get null here if (MatchFound!= null)
       MatchFound(this, EventArgs.Empty);

Comment: You really need to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because it's difficult to tell what you are trying to accomplish.  Which form is raising the event and which form is subscribing to it?  Your question is not very clear, especially because you use the same class names in both projects.  It's confusing.

Comment: @PeterPam can you show your attempt to implement the second event (listening to the event from classBB)? Then we have a better chance of fixing it

Comment: i've created a new post as i saw the basic problem is another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932595/how-to-fire-correctly-an-event-in-c-sharp