# How to correctly fire an event in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fire an event when button is clicked. I click the button and nothing happens.

The problem is I always get null as `EventA` in `OnEventA()`:

```
namespace eventsC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event EventHandler EventA;

        protected void OnEventA()
        {
            if (EventA != null)
                //never arrives here as EventA is always = null
                EventA(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnEventA();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Based on link from Henk Holterman I tested this code also:

```
public delegate void Eventhandler(object sender, Eventargs args);  

// your publishing class
class Foo  
{
    public event EventHandler Changed;    // the Event

    protected virtual void OnChanged()    // the Trigger method, called to raise the event
    {
        // make a copy to be more thread-safe
        EventHandler handler = Changed;   

        if (handler != null)
        {
            // invoke the subscribed event-handler(s)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);  
        }
    }

    // an example of raising the event
    void SomeMethod()
    {
       if (...)        // on some condition
         OnChanged();  // raise the event
    }
}
```

I call `OnChanged()` when I click a button but the result is still always the same: `EventA = null`.

Comment: Are there any subscribers to your event?

Comment: I wrote up the full picture [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448530/60761)

Comment: @PeterBons: i need to receive the event in another VB.NET project in the same solution. But never arrives due to the EventA = null. Can i fire the event from the same class like in the code i show?

Comment: Yes you can but it only works if there are subscribers. Once you add one you will see it is not null anymore.

Comment: @PeterBons: thanks for your response.Can you please tell me how to do this in the same class?

Comment: I think Henk Holterman gave the best link for that, otherwise I would only repeat his answer

Comment: i have tested code from this link and the problem is the same...

Comment: You do not provide enough information here for an answer - where is your line with `+=` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: i do not have

Comment: Yes, you must provide all of the relevant code - it must be a [mcve].

Comment: Re " i do not have" Then you do not have  a subcriber and in that case EventA is supposed to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace eventsC
{    

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> myEvent;

        protected void OnMyEvent()
        {
            if (myEvent != null)
                myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myEvent += Handler;

            //call all methods that have been added to the event
            myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnMyEvent();
        }


        static void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Handled!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer your question. Your question seems to ask about consuming your event from a different class. Is that right?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to override `OnMyEvent` and also handle the event in your own class.    The event handler should be done in the subscribing class, not in `Form1`

Answer (score 0):

I think they have correctly answered that it does not have any subscriber.

```
namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    public delegate void Eventhandler(object sender, EventArgs args);

    // your publishing class
    class Foo
    {
        public event EventHandler Changed;    // the Event

        protected virtual void OnChanged()    // the Trigger method, called to raise the event
        {
            // make a copy to be more thread-safe
            EventHandler handler = Changed;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                // invoke the subscribed event-handler(s)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        // an example of raising the event
        public void SomeMethod()
        {

                OnChanged();  // raise the event
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo objFoo = new Foo();
            objFoo.Changed += ObjFoo_Changed;
            objFoo.SomeMethod();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ObjFoo_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event fired and changed");
        }
    }
  }
```